# Получил уведомление о комментарии адресованном не мне

Tags: дефект, комментарии, уведомления

В инбокс пришло уведомление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011988/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E?noredirect=1#comment1718402_1011988) был адресован не мне.

Comment: Мгм. Очень странно по двум моментам: а) вы ни разу не отписывались под этим вопросом (значит, вас вообще невозможно пингануть из-под вопроса) б) этот комментарий не исправлялся, это первая и окончательная редакция. Выглядит так, будто баг: разослалось всем участникам сайта у которых логин начинается с "Sergeyпробел". (Интересно так ли это? Наверное, кто-нибудь уже давно бы заметил подобное поведение)

Comment: @AK возможно, я был первым, кто не только заметил, но и написал об этом. Впрочем, не исключено, что я был единственным, на ком этот баг сработал.

Comment: Поиск @имени осуществляется по первым трем буквам. То есть достаточно (at)Ser или (at)Ale (мне). Но почему уведомление было доставлено тому, кто не отметился в комментах - это вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, только если соответствие однозначно, иначе не должно отправляться вообще никому.

Comment: Отправилось, потому что редактировал вопрос. Плюс отправляется всем с кем совпало, уже был такой вопрос

Comment: @Grundy тогда точно баг, отправляться должно тому, кому адресовался комментарий.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, [tag:так-задумано] :-)